# Duda respecto a como "relacionar" datos de un textfield a un arreglo

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

Estoy haciendo un programa en el cual tenemos que hacer una agenda electrónica con un `JFrame`, dados estos vectores:

```
int[] numeros={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
String[] nombres={"","","","","","","","","",""};
String[] apellidos={"","","","","","","","","",""};
String[] direcciones={"","","","","","","","","",""};
String[] telefonos={"","","","","","","","","",""};
int[] edad={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

Yo agregué uno más que hará de índice general. Este índice "guardará" todos los vectores en uno. 
Osea el índice 0 de, números, nombres, apellidos, etc, para que cuando lo quiera mostrar al seleccionar índice "1" me muestre en los `JTextfield` correspondientes a cada uno.
Es correcto hacer lo siguiente?

```
private void txtnomActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
  String strindice = txtindice.getText();
  int i = Integer.parseInt(strindice);
  nombres[i] = txtnom.getText();
}
```

Mi duda general es, si yo ingreso en `txtindice` el 1 y eso lo convierto a `int` mediante `parseInt`. quedaría `int i=1`, ese valor que se ingrese, lo toma `nombres[i]` ?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: No se entiende muy bien la pregunta. Yo en tu caso crearía una estructura completa de una vez (algo así como un mapa o un array y dentro cada conjunto de datos completo. Y me pregunto, ¿por qué no usar un objeto `Persona` en lugar de usar arrays de datos separados? La POO facilita mucho las cosas en ese sentido.

Answer (score 0):

> Mi duda general es, si yo ingreso en txtindice el 1 y eso lo convierto a int mediante parseInt. quedaría int i=1, ese valor que se ingrese, lo toma nombres[i] ?

Si, es correcto. Lo que recibas de entrada por medio de un **Text Field** será un String, al convertirlo a int con *Integer.parseInt(....)* podrás usar ese número como indice para obtener el dato de tus arreglos.

Por cierto, esto:

```
int[] numeros={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
String[] nombres={"","","","","","","","","",""};
String[] apellidos={"","","","","","","","","",""};
String[] direcciones={"","","","","","","","","",""};
String[] telefonos={"","","","","","","","","",""};
int[] edad={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

son **arreglos** comúnmente conocidos como **arrays**. La palabra Vector no es apropiado.